# Something not working in this C code

Tags: javascript, c, for-loop, sum

I want to solve this problem and because I know JavaScript better than any other language I wrote it firstly in JavaScript and now I'm trying to translate it to C.

[image: Sample image]

This is my JavaScript code

```
var SUM=0,RES=1,n=prompt('Enter n'),i=1,j=1;
for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){

  SUM = 0;

  for(var j=1;j<=i;j++){

    SUM = SUM+ i/(2*j);

  }
  RES = RES * SUM
}
console.log(RES)
```

I **think** this is working well. I translated it to C and the result is:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) 
{
   int n,i,j;
   float SUM=0,RES=1;
   printf("n equals to ");
   scanf("%d", &n); 

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        SUM = 0;

        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){

            SUM = SUM + i/(2*j);

        }
        RES = RES * SUM;
    }
   return RES;
}
```

The JavaScript at least returns a number. The C code always returns 0. Where is the problem?

Comment: How are you checking the return code? `echo $?`?

Comment: Javascript doesn't discern between integers and floating point  numbers, C *does*. Your C version divides an integer by an integer, and the result of that calculation is `floor(i/(2*j))`. You should *not* make i or j doubles; add an explicit cast to double to either i or j, or -- simplest way -- change `2` to `2.0`.

Comment: @CharlieBurns yes, also prints 0

Comment: @CharlieBurns: what was that to prove? `RES` is a *float*!

Comment: There's a [closed form expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod%28sum%28k%2F%282*i%29%29+from+i+%3D+1+to+k%29+from+k+%3D+1+to+N) for the value, so why bother writing it in a loop?

Comment: You should print out the answer at the end of the loop instead of returning it.

Comment: `SUM += i / (2.0*j);`

Comment: @KerrekSB, the wolframalpha link you provided returns different number even from my JavaScript code. Does that mean that my JavaScript code is not written well

Comment: @KerrekSB I hardly think expressing this as a function of harmonic numbers is "closed form"

Comment: Can I just change `int n,i,j;` to `float n,i,j;`

Comment: @Jongware, no I just completely missed the boat on this one. Not enough coffee yet.

Comment: @Voltron: Harmonic forms can be computed with the digamma function... and anyway they're more "reusable" than the original expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tricked by integer division (a very common problem)!  If you change your one line to:

```
SUM = SUM + (float)i/(2*j);
```

The reason is because the result of integer division is another integer.  So whenever

```
i/2*j < 1 (for positive integers)
```

your result gets truncated to 0.  In your case that inequality is always true, so you're just adding up a whole lot of zeros.  Just cast i to a float first and then divide to get a double result.

Comment: It will always return an integer

Comment: Enve, did you try making the change?  I think you'll find that it works.  Even if the end result is an integer, your code as written still needs to deal with non-integers in the interim.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments you are doing integer devision  in this line

```
 SUM = SUM + i/(2*j);
```

which will return the result of an integer (like using the floor function)

you need to convert implicit variables in 1/(2*j) to a float or a double.

an integer/float is a float a integer/integer will return an integer.

a float times an integer is a float.

```
SUM = SUM + i/(2.0f*j);
```

should fix your problem by converting the denominator to a floating point number,

Comment: Indeed, but consider change the wording here: "you need to convert the *result*.." -- converting the result is too late. As you show further on, at least one of the arguments needs to be a float.